# Google map calls XML on dragend

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I have a database with a lot of poi's in mysql, and want to retrieve a 5 miles radius from wherever the user drag the center marker.
How can I 'call' the XML each time he does that?
Any hint?

I can pull XML from table and create the markers once the call is made, I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have an event listener for the dragend function on the marker.  Then within that function you need to do an ajax request to get your XML file.  Something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
// do ajax request, passing event.latLng.lat() and event.latLng.lng() to your other page
});
```